# React connecting Auth0Provider contains error in the app

Tags: reactjs

```
ReactDOM.render(
<Auth0Provider
domain="my-domain"
clientId="my-clientID"
authorizationParams={{
  redirect_uri: window.location.origin
}}
 > 
<App />
</Auth0Provider>,
document.getElementById("root")
);



Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function 
component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
```

I am trying to connect Auth0Provider with the React app and I followed the documentation thoroughly with the steps but the error shows the above error. I could not figure out even I followed the steps it still could not work the app properly